# I am not able to install my printer properly after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, samsung

I tried a lot but it is more a trial and error because I lack a basic understanding of the cups system which seems to be neccessary.
(The printer is okay, under 20.04 I was able to print, scan etc...)

my system:
two Thinkpad laptops (my wife and me) with Ubuntu 22.04  and we want to share one samsung C48x color printer usually connected via WLan an 192.168.2.199.
from a previous question I received the link to the actual samsung driver (uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz) and it is now under /home/uld extracted and installed with "sudo ./install.sh"...on both pc

I **was** able to print successfully from one PC, but I am not able to do the same from the other PC although they are quite simmilar; and now everything

my wish:
to be able to **use the printer from both PCs using the Wlan**

**questions**:

1. Do I have to use cups (2.4.1)  (I was not aware of such a service in Ubuntu 20.04)?
2. Is there a difference if I install a printer under cups via "localhost:631" or via the Ubuntu menu under "properties - printer"?
3. Is there an easy to understand step-by-step description how to use cups for various tasks (like mine) - preferably in german? (the description on localhost:631 are not easy to understand for me, therefore not helpful)

**the actual problems i struggle with**:

- when I turned on the printer the cups menu (add printer" shows 3 to 5 samsung c48 printers, sometimes double (e.g.

  - Samsung C48x Series on 192.168.2.199 (Samsung C48x Series)
  - Samsung C48x Series (SEC30CDA7B12411) (Samsung C48x Series)
  - Samsung C48x Series (driverless) (Samsung C48x Series)
  - Samsung C48x Series (Samsung C48x Series)
- which one to choose?
  (what I found out that these printers show different connections like dnssd..., socket..., ipp...local, ipp..., dnssd......uuid) => no idea what are the consequences
- sometimes (on the add-printer page) it shows something like "connection : 192.168.2.199" on the top of the list...shall I leave the checkbox activated ? what is the influence on following steps?
- once I choosed a printer to add, shall I activate the checkbox "approval for network" (netzwerkfreigabe) or not? In other words: if a printer is connected via Wlan and used by 2 PCs... is it a local printer for each pc or a network printer?
- then I have several options to assign a driver to my selected printer

  - Samsung C48 series - ipp everywhere
  - Samsung C48 series PS (en) (listed twice)
  - Samsung C48 series, driverless, cups filters 1.28.15 (en)
- no idea what is the difference and what are the consequences. I assume the drivers may relate to the different "versions" of the same printer as mentioned above

You may see, I am really lost and have no idea how to get forward. There are so many options I don't understand and so many possible combinations of these options... Hopefuly there are some patient guys out there with helpful hints...
dieter

Comment: The only german site I know is : https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/CUPS/

Comment: CUPS is a product of Apple and the best we get for printer config. At the end it all depends on the printer manufacturer keep to the protocol. At least Apple has some influence on printer manufacturers. Apple forces to the "driverless" model. Therefore a printer has to follow some rules. On the other side we have Microsoft, which has its own ideas. The printer propagate the capabilities to the network, that is what you see: ipp, lpr, cups-driverless.

Comment: many thanks for the hints! I knew this german description, but unfortunately it uses a lot of new words and concepts so it does not help me a lot...

Comment: but your hint on the differences between apple and microsoft helped me to understand why it is so difficult / confusing to install a simple printer under linux :-(

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I used the following solution

- disable automatic printer search in cups
- add manually my printer as Postscript printer using the IP address
  under -> settings -> printer
- install the related *.ppd file that defines all Postscript commands
  capable for my printer model (found on the web)
- define as default printer.

Now all applications are showing my printer in the respective print menu, independent if the printer is on or off ...
and all print jobs are printed, once the printer is turned on ...
and no more confusion about a lot of (automatically added) printer models which are not working properly